# Pandas syntax for multiple if statements using | and & operators

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I want to use the following syntax in Pandas to create an `if` condition using comparison operators, do I need to wrap the `or` conditions within their own parenthesis?

> Without extra parenthesis

```
df.loc[(df['Col1'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col2'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col3'] == 'No') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Yes') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Maybe'),
       ['Result']] = 'CORRECT'
```

> With extra parenthesis

```
df.loc[(df['Col1'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col2'] == 'Yes') &
       ((df['Col3'] == 'No') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Yes') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Maybe')),
       ['Result']] = 'CORRECT'
```

Or are both valid? It's hard to deduce from the documentation which should be correct.

Comment: It has nothing to do directly with pandas, but with operator precedence in Python. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence. The bitwise `and` (`&`) has precedence over bitwise `or` (`|`) so in this case the parenthesis are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[(df['Col1'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col2'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col3'].isin(['No', 'Yes', 'Maybe'])), 'Result'] = 'CORRECT'
```

But your statements are different:

@DeepSpace - comment:

> It has nothing to do directly with pandas, but with [operator precedence in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). The bitwise and (&) has precedence over bitwise or (|) so in this case the parenthesis are required.

```
np.random.seed(1245)

a = ['No', 'Yes', 'Maybe']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(a, size=(10, 3)), columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
```

---

```
df.loc[(df['Col1'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col2'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col3'] == 'No') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Yes') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Maybe'),
       'Result1'] = 'CORRECT'

df.loc[(df['Col1'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col2'] == 'Yes') &
       ((df['Col3'] == 'No') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Yes') |
       (df['Col3'] == 'Maybe')),
       'Result2'] = 'CORRECT'

df.loc[(df['Col1'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col2'] == 'Yes') &
       (df['Col3'].isin(['No', 'Yes', 'Maybe'])), 'Result3'] = 'CORRECT'

print (df)
    Col1   Col2   Col3  Result1  Result2  Result3
0  Maybe    Yes    Yes  CORRECT      NaN      NaN
1     No  Maybe     No      NaN      NaN      NaN
2    Yes     No  Maybe  CORRECT      NaN      NaN
3  Maybe    Yes     No      NaN      NaN      NaN
4    Yes    Yes  Maybe  CORRECT  CORRECT  CORRECT
5    Yes  Maybe    Yes  CORRECT      NaN      NaN
6  Maybe  Maybe    Yes  CORRECT      NaN      NaN
7  Maybe     No    Yes  CORRECT      NaN      NaN
8  Maybe  Maybe  Maybe  CORRECT      NaN      NaN
9    Yes    Yes     No  CORRECT  CORRECT  CORRECT
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, so wrapping the `or` conditions seems to result in the same as `isin`, and the first doesn't work which is what I'm experiencing. I'll use the `isin` version, thank you.